# What domain should I give this cookie?

Tags: c#, .net, cookies

I'm trying to call a web service from a c# application, with sessionID.
In order to do this I need to set the "Domain" header in a cookie.

In Fiddler it looks like - "ASP.NET_SessionId=izdtd4tbzczsa3nlt5ujrbf5" (no domain is specified in the cookie).

The web service is at - "http://[some ip goes here]:8989/MyAPI.asmx".

I've tried:
http://[ip] ,
http://[ip]:8989 ,
http://[ip]:8989/MyAPI.asmx

All of these cause runtime error.

**I've also tried the ip alone** (i.e. 100.10.10.10) , which doesn't cause a runtime error, and sets the cookie, but the cookie is never sent when I invoke a web method.

Here's my code for setting the domain:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentSessionID))
{
   req.CookieContainer=new CookieContainer();
   Cookie cookie = new Cookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", currentSessionID);
   cookie.Domain = GetCookieUrl();  //<- What should this be?
   req.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
}
```

So what should the domain be?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried 10.0.0.1:8989? Ignoring the http:// portion...

Comment: Can you post a link to the instructions telling you that you need to set the domain? I've never heard of this type of requirement for calling a web service, and I'm curious. Always looking to learn something new.

Comment: @David, I got that from trial and error. Omitting the domain causes an error where the compiler tells you you forgot to specify the domain.

Comment: @Oren A This is a .NET based service?

Comment: One other thing, have you tried setting the CookieContainer instance as you have done before the first call to the WS, then grabbing the instance out of the GetResponse() and using that on subsequent calls?

Comment: @Aaron, yes it is, it's a .asmx file

Comment: @Aaron, I'm not sure what you mean. After I got the session id, I add it to the request's cookie, for each request (I build a new request every time I invoke a web-service).

Comment: @Oren In the HttpWebRequest, the very first one, have you set the HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()? Then on the HttpWebResponse look inside the cookies to see what that domain is listed as...?

Comment: @Aaron: Will creating a new CookieContainer in the request, will influence the response? (and btw I know the WS's ip and everything because I write it and thanks to Fiddler).

Comment: @Oren Based on reading from MS site yes, it will allow the CookieContainer to get populated with a cookie, since that property is null by default...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer(VS.71).aspx I'm curious to see what a returned value is, versus crafting your own...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the cookie was not sent is that the request's content length should be set **after** adding the cookie, and not before.
The domain is the ip alone.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should simply be [ip].  Drop the http:// part of what you've tried.

According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx) on MSDN, your code should be

```
cookie.Domain = "100.10.10.10";
```

Next, exactly what error are you getting?  Also, are you confusing a Compile error with a Runtime error?  I find it hard to believe you are getting a compilation error as Domain is a String property which means you can put pretty much anything into it.

Finally, why are you sending a cookie to a web service?  The normal way is to pass everything in the form post or on the query string.

---

**Update**

BTW, if you absolutely must add a cookie to the header in order to pass it to a web service, the way you do this is (taken from [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/xlinesonegoal/archive/2008/10/10/send-cookie-in-http-header-webrequest-asp.net-c-web-services.aspx)):

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("fareId=123456"); //the data you want to send to the web service
HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
WebReq.Method = "POST";
WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
WebReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
WebReq.Headers["Cookie"] = "ASP.NET_SessionId=izdtd4tbzczsa3nlt5ujrbf5"

Stream PostData = WebReq.GetRequestStream();
```

Note that this sets the header inline with the request without instantiating a "cookie" object.  The Domain property of a cookie is to help ensure the cookie is only sent to the domain listed.  However, if you are initiating the request and trying to append a cookie to it, then the best way is to just add it as a string to the request headers.

Comment: I've tried ip alone (as I wrote in the question), the cookie is then not sent when I invoke a web-service.

Comment: you're right about the "time", Cookie is .NET's cookie (should I try httpCookie instead?), when I send a request with only the ip, it's not sent when I invoke the request (I know that from Fiddler). As to why sending a cookie, I'm quite sure that's what the browser does (again, Fiddler)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Simple function to get cookie domain
private string GetCookieDomain(string uri)
{
    Uri req_uri = new Uri(uri);
    return req_uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Host, UriFormat.Unescaped);
}
```