# In .NET, how do you provide a session identifier to a web service that requires authentication?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, web-services, authentication

I am using a web service that requires authentication from .NET (Visual Studio 2010). According to the documentation, you first request a session identifier from the first web service. I can do that with no problem. Then you are supposed to call the second web service for actually performing your query, passing the session identifier in a cookie. Here is my sample code:

```
AuthenticateService authenticate_service = new AuthenticateService();
string session_identifier = authenticate_service.Authenticate();

SearchService search_service = new SearchService();
search_service.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("Cookie", "SID=" + session_identifier, null, search_service.Url);
search_service.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);

search_service.Test();
```

However, I am getting the following exception on the last line:

**System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException was unhandled**
Message=Session ID cookie value cannot be null or empty string - It is required that the high level Web service client program participate in the session initialized by the server.

Does anybody know how to properly send a cookie with a session ID to a web service?

Comment: Have you verified that the session_identifier you received is not null? How about throwing an exception if its null? Could you test that?

Comment: I have put a breakpoint after this step to verify that I always get a valid session identifier, e.g. "2Wc2l48aAA5J5cepCeo". I should add an automated check on this but for simplicity I left it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out...

It all had to do with the `domain` parameter of the `Cookie` constructor. I was passing `search_service.Url` because I wasn't sure what it was supposed to be. Apparently it should have been something like `"search.google.com"`. When I passed that to the constructor instead, everything started working as expected.

Comment: I know it doesn't help, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916554/what-domain-should-i-give-this-cookie. I solved my own problem too (-:

Answer (score 0):

I found this somewhere along the line. It is a cookie-aware web-client that I have been using. This allows me to have the ease of use of `WebClient` and pass cookies.

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{

    private CookieContainer m_container = new CookieContainer();

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = m_container;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

Then you can just use the `WebClient` methods and the cookie is passed automatically after you authenticate.

Example code:

```
CookieAwareWebClient webClient = new CookieAwareWebClient();    
NameValueCollection data = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
data["user"] = "myusername"; //now holds a user=username map
byte[] response = webClient.UploadValues("http://localhost:8080/somewebservice/auth/","POST", data); //point to the webservice authentication URI
```

Now you can use `webclient.UploadFile` or `UploadValues` or whatever you want assuming that the previous authentication was OK.

Comment: I am not sure how exactly to incorporate this into my code. Is it possible to use a WebClient with web services? If so could you give an example?

Comment: Just use  CookieAwareWebClient webClient = new CookieAwareWebClient();    and now webClient will be cookie aware. Then you can use webClient.UploadValues pointed at the service with a username map and as long as you keep using that same webClient variable it is associated with that cookie